# mySQL trigger prevent delete from one table with condition on another

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables (Customers and Appointments)

Customers contains a list of customer details with primary key cust_id

Appointments contains details of appointments, with fields:
appt_date,
start_time and
customer (foreign key cust_id from table1)

I want to write a trigger which prevents you deleting a record from Customers if it is the only record in Appointments with that particular appt_date and start_time (a particular appt_date and start_time can have more than one customer).

Comment: Triggers? Don't you need another clause in you query that preventes the row from being deleted if you have such case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveRecord's callbacks to prevent.

Check this [page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

In your case, you should use before_destroy, and raise some validation exception.